# Can you write a webservice call in coldfusion without using createObject("webservice"....i.e. using Java

Tags: java, web-services, coldfusion, wsdl

I found this information on the Adobe website: [Consuming web services that ColdFusion does not generate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b4.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13a13-7ff7). However, I am still having problems authenticating with this web service: https://secure.eloqua.com/API/1.2/Service.svc?wsdl

The authentication does work, as I have managed to access the methods via .Net. Is it possible this is a web service that CF can't process?

The Eloqua site has code samples for Java, but it assumes a Java Dev Environment using Netbeans. Can you bypass the built in CF web service calls and do it directly in Java?

Comment: What are the exact errors you are getting when trying to use the WSDL?

Answer (score 1):

Eloqua is using WS-Security for SOAP messages which ColdFusion does not support (need Axis2).

BUT you can use Anthony Israel-Davis's cfWSAuthenticator, A ColdFusion CFC to add WS-Security to SOAP request -> https://github.com/anthony-id/cfWSAuthenticator

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks Fitzchev. Ill give it go and get back with the results.

Comment: I had a look at this and i think it would work but you have to hand craft all the soap envelopes xml which if it was 1 or 2 calls we were making it would be ok but we need to use thier apis quite a bit. At least we know CF cant do it (natively) so can move on. What i will try next is possibly doing it as a .net dll and then using the cf .Net service to make calls to the dll.  I think it can work in principle.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to this question, but I was able to make valid requests to a ws security SOAP service by building the request body and headers manually in ColdFusion without any external jars and without calling any java libraries directly. The [spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm) for WSS (Web Services Security) username token is quite simple. You can do something like the below to generate the security header and just add it to your custom built SOAP payload. The key is generating a compliant and unique nonce with every request along with a compliant created date/time.

If you need more info on building and sending the requests in general, take a look at [Making Soap Web Service Request with ColdFusion and CFHTTP](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-making-soap-web-service-requests-with-coldfusion-and-cfhttp.htm). Once you have built a cfc with various utility methods in place (send request, create security header, etc), it is a matter of creating specific functions corresponding to the API methods you want to call (load the wsdl in soapUI, copy/paste the request body into your cfc function, add arguments and business logic as needed, parse the response).

```
<cffunction name="generateSecurityHeader" access="private" returntype="string" output="false">
        <cfset var loc = structNew() />
        <cfsavecontent variable="loc.soapSecurityHeader">
            <cfoutput>
                <soapenv:Header>
                    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
                            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0##PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
                            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0##Base64Binary">#ToBase64(createUUID())#</wsse:Nonce>
                            <wsu:Created>#Dateformat(Now(),'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss')#Z</wsu:Created>
                        </wsse:UsernameToken>
                    </wsse:Security>
                </soapenv:Header>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfsavecontent>
        <cfreturn loc.soapSecurityHeader>
    </cffunction>
```